# IE9 HTTPS security is compromised by my Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, greasemonkey, internet-explorer-9

I’ve got a [Greasemonkey-for-IE](http://www.gm4ie.com/) script in IE9 that’s importing jQuery. But on secure pages it doesn’t work.

I’m getting:

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
```

The code that fails is:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", 
    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
```

How can I make this work? The script doesn’t cause a problem in Firefox.

Comment: @Chris: Disallowing mixed content by default is a feature, not a bug - it'll probably stay in the final release as well. Nothing wrong with testing on a beta (unless you're asking the SO dev team to do it for you ;)).

Comment: @Chris - any web developer who isn't testing their code in IE9 already is going to crash and burn when it is finally released.

Comment: @Spudley - That's a rather poor attitude to have about it...if my code works in a standards compliant way on every other browser already, it isn't me who should be adjusting my code...

Comment: @Spudley: IE9 seems, um, good *enough* in standards compliance to say that the developer might get a few hiccups, and perhaps a bruised knee; but the overall effect probably won't be "crash and burn".

Comment: @Nick - IE9 is a new browser. It is massively better than IE8, and is actually a pretty good browser. It has loads of new features. It also has new bugs, new quirks, and of course plenty of stuff it doesn't support. It is not 100% compatible either with other browsers or with standards. Just like every other browser out there. As a web developer, you should be testing in every browser that you want to support. Including IE9.

Comment: @Spudley - When it comes remotely close to properly implementing JavaScript, *then* I'll test...what's out isn't beta quality (e.g. it isn't feature complete), it's *hardly* alpha quality...testing in IE9? Sure, but not until it's remotely close to being finished. Right now it's a complete waste of time chasing quirks that are **their quirks**, not code I should fix. **It's not better than IE8** (yes, you read that right), **it will be** when it's finished, but currently it has a bunch of unknown issues that are question marks as to *if* they'll be fixed...IE8 is at least a known quantity.

Comment: @Spudley:  Compliant code is not going to crash and burn in a new browser.  I was just making a comment to a potentially new developer that currently you really do not have to "worry" about building production apps that work in IE9 just yet.  Testing/developing for it is cool but it was just a comment and see Nick Craver's comment above.

Comment: hehe, I'm not going to argue this any more. My point is this: my job as a web developer is to create sites that work for our users. When IE9 is released, a big enough proportion of our users are going to move to it that our site will need to work with it from day one (some of them are brave enough to already be using the beta as their main browser). Therefore it is included in our tests. (the 'crash and burn' thing was figurative, but the point remains that you need to be testing with it now)

Comment: @Spudley - What if I do test, find errors, then make changes only to find the bug fixed in a later IE9 beta...wasn't that a mis-use of everyone's time? That's my primary issue, testing against a moving target (when you *know* it's moving) is rarely as productive as waiting and testing a release candidate where changes are much less likely.

Comment: @Nick: All the browsers are moving targets.

Comment: IE9 is still buggy as hell. E.g. FABridge fails completely since cached SWFs do not expose their methods to the object tag. So I have to agree with Nick, testing against something that's work in progress isn't useful unless your target is to report bugs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Presumably: Use https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js instead (or not trust a third party CDN (to be both trustworthy and not compromised) for your secure pages)

Answer (score 38):

You can eliminate the issue with simpler code by using a scheme-relative URL like this:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", 
   "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
```

This will use `http://` on an `http://` page and `https://` on an `https://` page...a much simpler way to solve the issue.

Comment: Protocol-relative URLs are [now considered an anti-pattern](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). It's better to just explicitly use HTTPS instead.

Comment: @IanDunn I'm not disagreeing *in general*, but that's not universally true at all. There are performance concerns with SSL/TLS, regardless of what people running global data centers and no latency issues may tell you. As far as I'm aware, the speed of light hasn't changed recently, but I'll double check tomorrow :)

Answer (score 5):

The error message is IE's new way of warning about mixed content (HTTP and HTTPS resources on a secure page). [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/09/27/user-experiences-quieter-notifications.aspx?PageIndex=3) is a related MSDN blog post.

Using

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js
```

seems to work as well, although I can't see a official reference to it in the [Libraries API overview.](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery)

Comment: Check this as well. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/https-mixed-content-in-ie8.aspx?PageIndex=6

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you're in secure mode (ie HTTPS), all the files loaded by the page must also be HTTPS. The JQuery include you're making here is HTTP.

You need to detect whether the page is in HTTP or HTTPS mode (use `window.location.protocol()`), and adjust the URL of the JQuery include to suit. (all it needs is the additional 's' after 'http')

Answer (score 0):

you are using https connection and you want to access a http connection.