# IE9 Error SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised after redirect (plus "only secure content" message)

Tags: facebook, redirect, https, internet-explorer-9, facebook-javascript-sdk

I love it when something is working in other browsers and then ya fire up IE and it all goes poof.

I'm getting the following error:

`SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://www.example.com/myappname/?rctp=[an FB user id]`

Here's the workflow:

User goes to canvas app on Facebook. Makes choices on form, form submission goes to app's URL on my domain where quick database work is done and redirects back to the app with user id added as a GET variable, which is used to trigger a user-generated request in Request 2.0 fashion.

Works fine in Firefox. In IE9, I get the "*only secure content*" error message. IE9 F12 debugger console shows the above "*SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http*..." message.

Not sure why it's showing "**http**://www.example.com/myappname" as the url it's redirecting from is "**https**://www.example.com/myappname"

Again... works fine in Firefox. As per some of the other Q's I've seen here, I tried adding `FB._https = (window.location.protocol == "https:");` and `FB._https = true` to the JavaScript but to no avail.

UPDATE: Ok, removing the GET variable clears up the problem. But I NEED to pass that variable. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? What does "removing the GET variable" mean? Where are you removing it from? FB.init?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE9 HTTPS security is compromised by my Greasemonkey script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905840/ie9-https-security-is-compromised-by-my-greasemonkey-script)