# IE9 SEC7111 Error when accessing a frame over https

Tags: https, internet-explorer-9

When viewing the console in IE9 we receive this error, whenever we refresh a frame:

SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://awesome.com/frames/mainmenu.aspx

The error happens every time, however occasionally (maybe one in twenty) the frame does not load at all.

The frame is part of a frameset:

```
<FRAMESET id=FrameParent frameSpacing=0 border=0 frameBorder=0 rows=90,*>
  <FRAME frameSpacing=0 noResize src="mainmenu.aspx" frameBorder=0 
    name=MainMenu scrolling=no ?>
  <FRAME frameSpacing=0 noResize src="../mainpage.aspx" frameBorder=0
    name=MainContent scrolling=yes>
</FRAMESET>
```

Any help would be appreciated. The only related topics I've found online regarding this error are when accessing content over http, which would be reasonable.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905840/ie9-https-security-is-compromised-by-my-greasemonkey-script