# SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised using IE

Tags: internet-explorer-9, image-gallery

I'm having issues having this image gallery display in IE. http://www.campchiefouray.org/summer-camp-photos-2013.html Running this URL through developer tools in Browserstack I'm seeing the following error. Has anyone had this issue, and if so, where is this coming from , and most importantly how can I fix?! Any help would be appreciated.

SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised

http://www.campchiefouray.org/summer-camp-photos-2013.html

Comment: similar to this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905840/ie9-https-security-is-compromised-by-my-greasemonkey-script