# Uploadify basic demo page not working on IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, uploadify

All browsers apart from IE are working nicely with Uploadify in my project.

So just going to the demo page in IE10 :

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

I see that for IE the upload button is not properly changed to its Uploadify upload button.

On F12 debug, under console I can see the following error:

SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://gw079.lphbs.com/ConvivaCommunicationProxy.html

Does anyone know if this is causing the problem, and how I might fix it?

Flash plugin is displaying right for other sites.

I have 'reinstalled' IE10 without fixing the issue, and other browsers work fine on this demo page for me. Another guy in the office doesn't have the error in IE10, all works for him.

Comment: You could easily search for the SEC7111 and then you would find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905840/ie9-https-security-is-compromised-by-my-greasemonkey-script

Answer (score 0):

I removed this line from my site and it worked fine w/o having to edit any of my Uploadifive code

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically **Uploadify** work with FlashPlayer,latest browser are pre installed with it.But browser like IE8,IE10 should install separately.you should download adobe flash player Activex for internet explorer and install it [link](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html)