# Removing IE warning in HTTPS page

Tags: security, ssl, https

I have a page that is under SSL, I removed all references to non secure protocol (http) and still IE shows that annoying message that Only Secure Content is Displayed. What am I missing?

Comment: Here is that page BTW: https://application.ninono.ca/application_iframe.php

Comment: Are you running any content across multiple domains?

Comment: yeah, this page will be in iFrame of another website, which is also under SSL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems IE is unhappy with the way the JavaScript is coded (no offence). I get the following errors;

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://application.ninono.ca/application_iframe.php 
application_iframe.php
HTML1414: Unexpected character: U+0021 EXCLAMATION MARK (!) 
application_iframe.php, line 1175 character 45
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json/?callback=jQuery18209876018980527811_1384276461967&screen_name=mosaicprodesign&include_rts=true&count=5&include_entities=true&_=1384276463813 
application_iframe.php
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://application.ninono.ca/application_iframe.php 
application_iframe.php
```

Looking further into SEC7111, which is what is causing the problem, it seems to be related to this article; [IE9 HTTPS security is compromised by my Greasemonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905840/ie9-https-security-is-compromised-by-my-greasemonkey-script)

I am no JavaScript dev so I can't tell you how to solve it unfortunately, but hopefully this can put you on track, especially the api.twitter call needs to be https for sure.