# IE9 HTTPS security is compromised by, ...https! why?

Tags: ssl, https, internet-explorer-9

This is simillar to several questions here about getting this message when insert a non https script on a page, such as [IE9 HTTPS security is compromised by my Greasemonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905840/ie9-https-security-is-compromised-by-my-greasemonkey-script)

but while testing my code in the modernIE vm for win7+IE9, i get this error for a https page!

it says:

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://example.com/script.js
```

i already double checked the cert. everything looks good. If i open the same script directly on the address bar they load just fine and there is no complains about the certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out to be bad root certs on the test box. apparently all other browsers ship with their own certs and were not affected by this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the request for your script is not redirected from https to plain http? This would not matter if you access it directly from the address bar because it is not included in a secure context. But, if included in a secure context it would cause this warning.

Comment: Nope. it is not. 1) in any other browser it does not trigger the warning. 2) on the address bar, i can click the pad lock and confirm that i get the correct cert path and "This certificate is OK." in the cert status box. It is all good.

Comment: Does the script you include itself tries to load or redirect to other resources? I don't know what you include but especially scripts outside of your control (like advertisements) might behave strange and might change the behavior depending on the browser and how they get included, sometimes to circumvent detection of malware (malvertising).

Comment: good point. but no. it does a also valid https request inside. But that was the best lead I had so far so i went to double check the network tab on the F12 tool, and all requests show as http, except one image on the page (totally unrelated to the script flow). though that image renders just fine without any complains... O.o

Comment: btw, the scripts in the warning loads and executes fine. I'm starting to think i should just ignore it...